# group by date in mongoDB while spliting each date's data to two categories

Tags: mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, grouping

I am working on a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63524766/group-by-date-in-mongodb-while-counting-other-fields) and the answer posted there helped me figure out how I can work with my problem.

Additional question I have is - how can I modify my query if I want my output in the following format? :

```
{"label": "2020-08-21", "value": 5, "A": 2, "Others": 3}
```

(example output `{"label": "2020-08-21", "value": 7, India: 3, Others: 4})`

Thank you in advance!! :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can simply group:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      createdAt: {$dateToString: {format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$timestamp"}},
      recipe: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$createdAt",
      A: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$recipe", "A"]}, 1, 0]}},
      value: {$sum: 1}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0, label: "$_id", value: 1, A: 1, other: {$subtract: ["$value", "$A"]}
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I2sUCsnG3lU)